# Company Websites Share Credentials - How do I sync credentials between websites in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, passwords, firefox-extensions, password-management

I think it's pretty common for companies to operate several internal websites, which use the same (LDAP?) credentials. I believe it's also fairly common for that password to need to be changed every 2-30 weeks.

Given this is a common use-case, I assume there must be some way to indicate to the browser that these websites all share a single login. How do I set this up, specifically in Firefox, so that I only have to update a stored password once per time it changes, instead of having to update several (identical) stored credentials for every website where it's used?

IE, at my company we use the same login for multiple instances of Jenkins, multiple instances of GitHub, several instances of OpenShift, Splunk, Sysdig, and several other tools... we have a single website where we update them all once every few months.

Is there a browser with this feature built-in? Are there plugins or extensions available that give me this feature? In all my years of using Firefox, Safari, and Chrome, I've never seen anything like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by credentials you mean user-name/password,
you would need to use a password manager that has the concept of equivalent domains.
It's possible that such an option will require the non-free version.

For example,
[LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/?utm_source=logmein.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=hp-bb)
has the option of
[Equivalent Domains](https://support.logmeininc.com/lastpass/help/duplicate-stored-passwords-across-multiple-sites-lp040007)
that allows defining relationships such as:

[image]

I haven't found this option in the free version of LastPass, so it probably needs
the Premium version, at
[€2.90*/month, billed annually](https://www.lastpass.com/pricing).

Comment: Thanks for the term "Equivalent Domains" - that gave me something new to search for. I found bitwarden - it's free version appears to include this feature. I'll see whether it works out for me.